# Live Data return old response then New response always in toast in User Registration using Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**
: When i press register button for register new user it show register success response in toast from live data, but when i tried to do same button trigger it show again register success response message from API & then also show phone number exist response from API in toast. It means old response return by live data too. So how can i solve this recursive live data response return issue?

**HERE is the problem video link to understand issue**
Check here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-hKGQh9k0EIYJcbInwjD5dB33LXV5GEn/view?usp=sharing

**NEED ARGENT HELP**

**My Api Interface**

```
interface ApiServices {

    /*
    * USER LOGIN (GENERAL USER)
    * */
    @POST("authentication.php")
    suspend fun loginUser(@Body requestBody: RequestBody): Response<BaseResponse>

}
```

**My Repository Class**

```
class AuthenticationRepository {

    var apiServices: ApiServices = ApiClient.client!!.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    suspend fun UserLogin(requestBody: RequestBody) = apiServices.loginUser(requestBody)
}
```

**My View Model Class**

```
class RegistrationViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    val respository: AuthenticationRepository = AuthenticationRepository()

    private val _registerResponse = MutableLiveData<BaseResponse>()
    val registerResponse: LiveData<BaseResponse> get() = _registerResponse

    /*
    * USER REGISTRATION [GENERAL USER]
    * */
    internal fun performUserLogin(requestBody: RequestBody, onSuccess: () -> Unit) {
        ioScope.launch {
            isLoading.postValue(true)
            tryCatch({
                val response = respository.UserLogin(requestBody)
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    mainScope.launch {
                        onSuccess.invoke()
                        isLoading.postValue(false)
                        _registerResponse.postValue(response.body())
                    }
                } else {
                    isLoading.postValue(false)
                }

            }, {
                isLoading.postValue(false)
                hasError.postValue(it)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**My Registration Activity**

```
class RegistrationActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityRegistrationBinding>() {

    override val layoutRes: Int
        get() = R.layout.activity_registration

    private val viewModel: RegistrationViewModel by viewModels()


    override fun onCreated(savedInstance: Bundle?) {
        toolbarController()


        viewModel.isLoading.observe(this, {
            if (it) showLoading(true) else showLoading(false)
        })


        viewModel.hasError.observe(this, {
            showLoading(false)
            showMessage(it.message.toString())
        })


        binding.registerbutton.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.registerCheckbox.isChecked) {
                try {
                    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                    jsonObject.put("type", "user_signup")
                    jsonObject.put("user_name", binding.registerName.text.toString())
                    jsonObject.put("user_phone", binding.registerPhone.text.toString())
                    jsonObject.put("user_password", binding.registerPassword.text.toString())
                    val requestBody = jsonObject.toString()
                        .toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                    viewModel.performUserLogin(requestBody) {
                        viewModel.registerResponse.observe(this){
                            
                           showMessage(it.message.toString())
                          //return old reponse here then also new reponse multiple time
    
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            } else {
                showMessage("Please Accept Our Terms & Conditions")
            }
        }
    }

    override fun toolbarController() {
        binding.backactiontoolbar.menutitletoolbar.text = "Registration"
        binding.backactiontoolbar.menuicontoolbar.setOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
    }

    override fun processIntentData(data: Uri) {}

}
```

Comment: this is expected behavior. Create your own single data emitter.

Comment: to make it simple, I use a boolean. once data is observed, I make it false. after button click and data is fetched, I assign true to the variable.

Comment: @MohammadTauqir Any sample code do you have/Repo?

Comment: https://medium.com/@abhiappmobiledeveloper/android-singleliveevent-of-livedata-for-ui-event-35d0c58512da

https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70

https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your registerResponse live data observe inside button click listener, so that's why it's observing two times! your registerResponse live data should observe data out side of button Click listener -

override fun onCreated(savedInstance: Bundle?) {
toolbarController()

```
    viewModel.isLoading.observe(this, {
        if (it) showLoading(true) else showLoading(false)
    })
    
    viewModel.registerResponse.observe(this){
       showMessage(it.message.toString())
    }


    viewModel.hasError.observe(this, {
        showLoading(false)
        showMessage(it.message.toString())
    })


    binding.registerbutton.setOnClickListener {
        if (binding.registerCheckbox.isChecked) {
            try {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                jsonObject.put("type", "user_signup")
                jsonObject.put("user_name", binding.registerName.text.toString())
                jsonObject.put("user_phone", binding.registerPhone.text.toString())
                jsonObject.put("user_password", binding.registerPassword.text.toString())
                val requestBody = jsonObject.toString()
                    .toRequestBody("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull())
                viewModel.performUserLogin(requestBody) {
                    
                }
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            showMessage("Please Accept Our Terms & Conditions")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LiveData` is a state holder, it's not really meant to be used as an event stream. There is a number of articles however about the topic like [this one](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) which describe the possible solutions, including [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) implementation taken from google samples.

But as of now kotlin coroutines library provides better solutions. In particular, [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html) are very useful for event streams, because they implement [fan-out](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#fan-out) behaviour, so you can have multiple event consumers, but each event will be handled only once. [Channel.receiveAsFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/receive-as-flow.html) can be very convenient to expose the stream as flow. Otherwise, [SharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) is a good candidate for event bus implementation. Just be careful with `replay` and `extraBufferCapacity` parameters.